# Find out if the leaves of a BST terminate at the same level

Tags: c, binary-tree, binary-search-tree

I am dealing with a BST and i want to write a function that checks if all the leaves terminate at the same level.

My first thought was to just get the height of left and right sub-tree and see if they are equal however I realized this is a wrong approach since i can have a scenario where the right child of root can be null and the leaves on the left sub-tree terminate at the same level.

Now I am kind of lost how to approach this problem.

My Code

```
int isCompleteBst(struct tree *t)
{
  if(t->root == NULL)
  {
    return 0;
  }
  else
  {
    return isCompleteBst_r(t->root);
  }
}
int isCompleteBst_r(struct leaf *lf)
{
   if(geHeight(lf->left) == getHeight(lf->right))
   {
     return 1;
   }
   else
   {
     return 0;
   }
}
```

Comment: So what's your expected output on that counterexample?

Comment: well for that case my logic would return 0(false) however i should be getting 1(true)

Comment: Can you not just write a recursive algo?  What does your data strcture look like?  Do you have sample code for the first try you did? Could you edit your question and add those two parts.

Comment: @Soren i posted the code i have but it's a wrong approach unfortunately..

Comment: @user2733436 -- the recursion should make a partial decision for each subtree and then pass the information up -- see the answer I provided below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First get the depth of any one leaf and store it. It will be used for comparison.

Then recurse trough the tree:

If you find a node with both children valid, continue recursion in both.

If you hit a node that has both left and right child NULL, you found the leaf, compare the current depth with the stored depth. If it doesn't match stop the recursion and return false. Otherwise continue with the recursion in both left and right children.

If you hit a node that has one child NULL and one valid, stop recursion since the depth obviously doesn't match, and return false.

If you never hit a false condition, return true by default.